# How to set GPU count to 0 using os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] =""?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, nvidia, python-os

So I have the following GPU configured in my system:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 461.33       Driver Version: 461.33       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100S-PCI...  TCC  | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P0    25W / 250W |      1MiB / 32642MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100S-PCI...  TCC  | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P0    25W / 250W |      1MiB / 32642MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, via python, I have to set the environment, such that, GPU count = 0.
I have tried the following, after learning from various sources:

```py
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
import torch
torch.device_count()
```

But, it still gives me the output as "2" as in for 2 GPUs in the system.
How to set the environment, such that it outputs "0" ?

Any other way, to set the count to "0" is also appreciated but it should be any ML-Library agnostic. (For example, I can't use `device = torch.device("cpu")` as this will work only for Pytorch and not for other libraries)

Comment: Are you trying to globally set this value to be 0 or for CUDA to be ignored in all instances by all librarys? I think `torch.cuda.device_count()` eventually talks directly with the CUDA API itself so will always return the actual count not what the environment variable is set to.

Comment: Yes, I want all instances in all ml libraries to think that 'no GPUs are available/visible'

Comment: Not able to reproduce. But I had to use `torch.cuda.device_count()`, not `torch.device_count()`. It correctly changes the number of GPUs to 0 for me.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent your GPU from being used, set `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to run `python` with the correct environment set. For example, on Linux

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python ...
```

The following should also work:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
```

But this must be done before you **first** import `torch`.

What I think is happening in your case is you must be importing `torch` earlier, perhaps indirectly via some libraries that use `torch`.

Answer (score 1):

`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"`

should set you to not use GPUs.  From https://sodocumentation.net/tensorflow/topic/10621/tensorflow-gpu-setup#run-tensorflow-on-cpu-only---using-the--cuda-visible-devices--environment-variable-

Answer (score 0):

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"
torch.cuda.device_count() # result is 2

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
torch.cuda.device_count() # result is 1, using first GPU

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
torch.cuda.device_count() # result is 1, using second GPU

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer, however, does not solve the question at hand. Please consider updating the answer in case you know how to make the `torch.cuda.device_count()` as zero.